# NpgSQL error "FATAL: 28000" in using postgreSQL through .NET

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

Until today I uses PostgreSQL very successfully through (VB) .NET.
I don't know how I may cause this in my IDE but I can't open any form's designer inside a project anymore. Instead of opening it error page appear with message:

> FATAL: 28000: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet.

If I run this project everything behaves OK including PostgreSQL functions.

Did anybody faces with that and what should I do to get back wanted functionality and be able to edit my designers with mouse?

Windows 7, PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Well, what changed recently?

Comment: I am not aware of any changes I made. Since this is windows some system update may cause this. But I believe I am not only one who get "this" and that someone with specific experience may help.